# I can't find the Hair option in my 'Render Properties'

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hair, properties

I'm trying to follow a tutorial and they enable the 'Hair Shape type Strip' in their 'Render Properties'. I can't find it in mine. I've tried looking around online too but I can't find an answer. Has it been moved somewhere else? or removed entirely?

I'm on Blender 3.2.1 btw

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender 3.3 introduces a [new Curves object type](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.3/Nodes_Physics) that will supersede the hair particle system in the future.

It looks like a few hair related things have already been **renamed** in Blender 3.2.

The **Hair** section is now called **Curves**. It's below the *Performance* section in your screenshot, well, in the middle. Just expand it to see the familiar options.

Furthermore, the **Hair Info** node in the *Shader Editor* is now called **Cuves Info**.

Comment: Yoooooo found it! Thank you very much!